# Saving previous variable to test against next variable, Scala, SQL

Tags: java, sql, scala, variables

I'm trying to save the previous value in order to test against my next value which is pulled from a sql database. The problem that I am having is that everytime I try to save the value before calling next, after calling next the value changes to the current value. Which basically means that my if statement never fails.

Please let me know of some way that I can keep the previous value in order to test it with the next value in the if test.

Please let me know:

```
i = 0
var lag_w_cap = 100000
var lag_code = "aaa"
var lag_date = new java.sql.Date(1900,06,30)

while(result_strength.next()) { //calling next line


  if(result_strength.getString("secr_code")==lag_code){
    lag_w_cap = result_strength.getInt("total_current_assets") -   
    result_strength.getInt("total_current_liabilities")
  } else {
    lag_w_cap = 1000000
  }

  logger.info(lag_w_cap)

  lag_code = result_strength.getString("secr_code") //trying to save old values
  lag_date = result_strength.getDate("stat_date")

  i += 1
}
```

Comment: You could simply return that value from your SQL statement using the `lag()` function. All modern DBMS support that nowadays.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that push was all I needed.